# Computing the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\left\lVert\vec{r}_n\right\rVert^4}$

Tags: summation

I try to compute the sum of the inverse distances to the fourth power of all unit cubes inside $\mathbb R^3$:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\left\lVert\vec{r}_n\right\rVert^4}$$

with cartesian coordinates this sum becomes:

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\sum_{j=-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{(n^2+k^2+j^2)^2},$$

where the term $(n,k,j)=(0,0,0)$ is excluded. After some calculations (using symmetry, etc.) I arrived at the simpler sums:
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\sum_{j=-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{(n^2+k^2+j^2)^2}=8\cdot\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n^2+k^2+j^2)^2}+12\cdot\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n^2+k^2)^2}+6\cdot\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^4}$$

The last two sums are equal to $2\pi^2G-\frac{\pi^4}{15}$, where $G$ is Catalan's constant, but I don't know to analyticly compute the first sum (if even possible) or any tricks how to tackle a triple sum. Does anybody know, if the triple sum has a nice analytic value or how someone might compute it?

Comment: Here's a whole book about this sort of thing: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Lattice-Sums-Encyclopedia-Mathematics-Applications/dp/1107039908 I don't know whether it has a formula for your sum though.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown the problem with lattice sums is, that they are alternating. But still thanks for the quick answer

Comment: But your lattice sum is non-alternating.

Answer (score 1):

Determining whether or not that sum has a "nice closed form" is an [open problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/228760/is-special-value-of-epstein-zeta-function-in-3-variables-a-period) in number theory.

Comment: Do you know if $\sum_{x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}}' \frac{1}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2}$ has a good approximation?